# mysql query to find all possible like combinations start with and ends with (simplified duplicate)

Tags: mysql

```
-- Sample data, borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/808921

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `groupname` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sm` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `code` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`groupname`) VALUES
  ('100:2000'),
  ('100:2001'),
  ('101:2000'),
  ('101:2001'),
  ('102:2002'),
  ('103:2003');
INSERT INTO `sm` (`code`) VALUES
  ('100'),
  ('101'),
  ('2000');
```

SQL Fiddle of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54714e/39

In MySQL, I would like to filter only the group names that contains various combinations of values in the sm table. i.e. 100,101,2000.

The below query returns other combinations too like

```
100:2000
100:2001
101:2000
101:2001
```

SQL:-

```
select distinct d.groupname from docs d, sm s  where d.groupname like concat(s.code,'%') or d.groupname like concat('%',s.code);
```

Original question:-

[mysql query to find all possible like combinations start with and ends with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57166271/mysql-query-to-find-all-possible-like-combinations-start-with-and-ends-with)

**Update:-**

Expected results:-

```
100:2000
101:2000
```

Comment: Just store the data properly.

Comment: Whats your expected result?

Comment: Thanks, updated the thread for expected results.

Comment: `select distinct d.groupname from docs d
join sm s1 on
d.groupname like concat(s1.code,'%')
join sm s2 on
d.groupname like concat('%',s2.code);`

Comment: Wow Tamil it's working mate.. [ pinniteenga :-) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just broke your `or` condition into make multiple `join` with the same table like below to achieve your expected result,

```
select distinct d.groupname from docs d
join sm s1 on
d.groupname like concat(s1.code,'%')
join sm s2 on
d.groupname like concat('%',s2.code);
```